# redirecting requests based on the body tomcat

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I have a tomcat 7 application which I can get requests from external sources.

Most of them call my request like this:

http://localhost:8080/MyWeb/exRequest

and I build servlet with URL pattern inside MyWeb app.

However, one external source must send the request like this:

http://localhost:8080/

and in the body:

```
<xml name="test" />
```

Since I don't want to declare a general servlel (like tomcat default) since it means that any request will need to go through my servlet, I thought to change index.jsp of ROOT to redirect to my servlet.

Is it the best option?

Is there an option to create a default servlet that will be invoked only if there is a special parameter in the body?

**EDITED**

Please note that I get the requests to localhost:8080 and not localhost:8080/MyWeb - it's general to tomcat and not to a specific web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't choose a servlet to invoke based on the request body, but you can set a servlet as the "welcome-file" in your web.xml.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.y.MyWelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

If you want to preserve the "welcome" function of some existing index.jsp, your servlet could forward requests without the correct XML in the body to an index.jsp file located under the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: The problem is that I get notification to the tomcat: localhost:8080 and not to localhost:8080/MyWeb where I could locate these definitions in web.xml of MyWeb

Comment: @Odelya - Okay, I see now. If the client that makes this request is so inflexible that it can't switch to the proper URL, it's unlikely to follow a redirect response. Seems like your best bet is to move the entire web application to `ROOT`, then, re-map your existing servlets to include the old application context name in their path. For example, if the servlet was `exRequest`, and the context `MyWeb`, it would move to the `ROOT` context, and be mapped as `MyWeb/exRequest`.

Comment: It's exactly what I thought to do. to move the application to root

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create a `Filter` and forward/redirect to a specific servlet whenever the request meets certain conditions.

If using servlet 3.0 map it with `@WebFilter`, otherwise use `web.xml` and `<filter>` + `<filter-mapping>`. You should map it be executed before the default servlet.

Comment: No - for is it the option or it's better to create a filter for ALL the request? Since when I use the change of index.jsp of the ROOT it's ONLY for localhost:8080/ request, otherwise it will be for all the requests

Comment: Passing through a filter is insignificant performance-wise. And you can map the filter to just /

Comment: I appreciate your help but it's not what I meant. See the edited question to explain more

Comment: the edit doesn't change things very much - you can deploy ROOT.war with your own filter definitions

Comment: @Bonzho I actually thought that it's better to create proxy in tomcat to forward localhost:8082/ to the servlet (the external vednor can change the port